# Rails Error: ActionController::UnknownFormat is missing a template for this request format and variant

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form in index page and I want that the action will be executed by Ajax, to display the result in the Index page.
This is my form in the index Page:

```
        <%= form_with model: @shopping, :url => {:action => "searchByDates"}, remote: true do |form| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.label :date_start %>
            <%= form.date_field :date_start, attribute: 'date' %>
            <%= form.label :date_end %>
            <%= form.date_field :date_end, attribute: 'date' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.submit "Cerca", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

This is my controller action:

```
  def searchByDates
    @date_start = params[:date_start]
    @date_end = params[:date_end]
    @shoppings = Shopping.where(:date_shopping => @date_start..@date_end)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And this is my searchByDates.js.erb, in the folder of the view

```
$('#shoppingTable').html("<%= j render partial: 'shoppinglists' %>");
```

I have added the route in the routes.rb file`post 'shoppings/searchByDates'`

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the param `format` on your form.

```
    <%= form_with model: @shopping, url: { action: "searchByDates" }, format: :js, remote: true do |form| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.label :date_start %>
            <%= form.date_field :date_start, attribute: 'date' %>
            <%= form.label :date_end %>
            <%= form.date_field :date_end, attribute: 'date' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.submit "Cerca", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

also I would modify the route to something like `post "shoppings/searchByDates", to: shoppings/search_by_dates, as: shoppings_search_by_dates` so you have snakecased actions while keeping the camelCase route, in that way the `url` param could be something like `url: shoppings_search_by_dates_path`

Comment: Thanks, now I don't get the error. But now there is another problem, after render partial, in the browser console there is the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '$', "$('#shoppi"... is not valid JSON

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems to be another, it seems that it doesn't consider the remote: true, and when calls the action does a redirect instead to respond with javascript. This is my form now <%= form_with model: @shopping, :url => {:action => "search_by_dates"}, format: :js, remote: true do |form| %>

Comment: well the `$` is for jquery, so I asume you have that already loaded, is it parsing the erb in the code? you should see the evaluation of this code `<%= j render partial: 'shoppinglists' %>`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I think that the problem was that it did not recognize the `remote: true` option, in fact it did always a redirect to the shoppings/search_by_dates URL, and that was the reason why it raised the "missing template" error, it searched for a view that I did not create, because I wanted the action to be called via Ajax.
I changed remote: true, with local: false in the form:

```
<%= form_with url: shoppings_search_by_dates_path, local: false do |form| %>
```

This is the search_by_dates action

```
  def search_by_dates
    @shoppings = nil
    @date_start = params[:date_start]
    @date_end = params[:date_end]
    @shoppings = Shopping.where(:date_shopping => @date_start..@date_end).order(date_shopping: :asc)
    @result_total_price = @shoppings.sum(:total_price)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And I renamed the js.erb file search_by_dates.js.erb